# Breadcrumbs/menu for dynamic pages

Tags: views, 8, navigation, breadcrumbs

Im breaking my head around getting the breadcrumbs set properly on views page.

my views' page address is "`teachers/%`" where % is a term-id.

I have a content type called '`program`' with a field taxonomy term reference field "field_department"

I want to set my breadcrumb for the page  '`teachers/%`' to be the breadcrumbs of the program associated with `%` + the program itself.

**my site is using also menu_breadcrumb** which gives the rule for my program breadcrumbs.

**I want the the breadcrumb of '`teachers/7`' will behave as if it is the menu child of `node/22`.**

I tried both hook altering the breadcrumbs or adding the pages to the menu dynamically but I dont manage.

Can this be done? and how?

Answer (score 1):

Views breadcrumbs can be tricky. You can create a module and a class that implements `BreadcrumbBuilderInterface` and do:

```
class MyBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * The AdminContext service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\AdminContext
   */
  protected $adminContext;

  /**
   * The AliasManager service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManagerInterface
   */
  protected $aliasManager;

  /**
   * The EntityTypeManager service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(
    AdminContext $admin_context,
    AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager,
    EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
  ) {
    $this->adminContext = $admin_context;
    $this->aliasManager = $alias_manager;
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) : bool {
    if ($this->adminContext->isAdminRoute()) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    // Using route_match, check if the current route is a view and which view id
    // and return true or false
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) : Breadcrumb {
    $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();

    // create your breadcrumbs...

    return $breadcrumb;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! It is the part of " // create your breadcrumbs..." that i am not sure how to do. I have the nid of the node I want to inherit from but how do I get its breadcrumbs? i wish there were something like Breadcrumb::load($node);

Comment: You are building your own chain here - so you would have to leverage other means. Like using entityTypeManager to load a node and get its information. If your first argument is a term ID, I am not sure how you would derive any sort of node id out of that (in this case, 22?) to load and attach information from?

Comment: I use entity query. i got that part of the code already. as for building my trail of breadcrumbs. **how can i know what breadcrumb trail my node has**? it is ruled by its location in the menu, i could perhaps load the menu and build the breadcrumbs from there, but im hoping for a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i did this way:

```
 public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) : Breadcrumb {
    $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
    $this->menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
    $node_id = 22; //I use a query to get the entities according to the routeMatch argument
    $results = $this->menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $node_id));
    foreach ($results as $result){
      if ($result->getMenuName() == "main"){
        $links = $this->_build_links($result,[Link::createFromRoute(t('Home'), '<front>')]);
        //here i use just a string 'Home', ideally this string should be taken from breadcrumbs\site settings.
      }
    }
    $breadcrumb->setLinks($links);
    return $breadcrumb;
  }
  private function _build_links($menu_item, $links){
    if ($menu_item->getParent() && $parent = $this->menu_link_manager->createInstance($menu_item->getParent())) {
     $links = $this->_build_links($parent, $links);
    }
    $title = $menu_item->getTitle();
    $routeName = $menu_item->getRouteName();
    $routeParameters = $menu_item->getRouteParameters();
    $options = $menu_item->getOptions();
    $links[] = Link::createFromRoute($title,$routeName,$routeParameters,$options);

  return $links;
}
```

I was pretty close to hooking up with the code of menu_breadcrumbs but I think there is an issue with the code there that prevents this kind of use 
see [issues/3026188](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb/issues/3026188)

My code is still not perfect and I would really still want to find a way to access and chain the breadcrumbs of "parent" node(node/22) in a more general way.